# how to share the csv file to whatsapp in objective c

Tags: ios, csv, whatsapp

how to share the csv file to whatsapp in objective  . i will try to share the csv file show the error message . "This item cannot be shared. Please select a different item.”

Answer (score 1):

csv file format is not possible to share in whatsapp.

WhatsApp accepts the following types of content:

- text (UTI: public.plain-text)
- photos (UTI: public.image)
- videos(UTI: public.movie)
- audio notes and music files(UTI:public.audio)
- PDF documents (UTI: com.adobe.pdf)
- contact cards (UTI: public.vcard)
- web URLs (UTI: public.url)

Please see this link
https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/iphone/23559013.